# AEM 6.0: Search a keyword in all files and components

Tags: aem

I am using `AEM 6.0` and **CRXDE Lite** to manage content. I need to find whereabouts of some HTML content. CRXDE Lite home page search shows me nothing. Moreover, its not just the HTML / JS / CSS / JSP files in which I need to search, but also inside the value properties of components (in which user might put some HTML content).

I am beginner in CQ / AEM. Could anybody please suggest me how can I search all the files plus values of all components, to find my HTML?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CRXDE Lite search, It should show all your content. You can install SP3 and give a try...

Otherwise you can use **AEM query builder API** to search form JCR. You will get the result in JSON format.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Best way to search code content, component properties, etc is by syncing crxde with eclipse using VLT and making use of eclipse search feature(ctrl + h) to search what you want. Use [VaultClipse](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vaultclipse/) eclipse plugin to setup the connection.